# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined discord embeds to detect emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I had this same issue with title but got solution, idk where i messed up with this one. I am tryna detect emojis in an embed.

```
for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
    if (message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].description.includes("✨")) {
          console.log('Emoji detected');
          break;

        }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

The error I got is

```
if (message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].description.includes("✨")) {
                                                           ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error suggests that the `description` property does not exist. Have you checked if it is defined?

Comment: The error clearly states what doesn't work. You need to check whether the `message.embeds[i]` has a property called `description` first.

Comment: Seems like your message.embeds[i].description property is undefined

Comment: `message.embeds[i] && message.embeds[i].description && message.embeds[i].description.includes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), the field `message.embeds` is an array of `MessageEmbed` objects, which are composed of multiple fields, including the field `description`.

[image]

The interesting part to look at in the documentation is the type of the fields. Here the field `description` have a type `?string`. The `?` tells you that the field may not be here. That's why you have an error in your loop. You gotta check if the field is there before trying to use it.

---

**Example :**

```
for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
    if (message.embeds[i] &&
        message.embeds[i].description &&
        message.embeds[i].description.includes('✨')) {
          console.log('Emoji detected');

          break;
    }
}
```

---

**Example in ES6 :**

```
if (message.embeds.some(x => x.description && x.description.includes('✨'))) {
   console.log('Emoji detected');
}
```